# Laravel adding standard css class to form fields

Tags: php, laravel, forms

Knowing that I can add classes to form fields in Laravel by providing a `class="<css class>"` to the call in the view like so:

`{{ Form::password('password', ['class' => 'form-control']) }}`

I came to wonder if you could define some kind of standard to do that. The desired effect would be, if I switched away from Bootstrap for example, I would have to change this in one spot only.

Looking forward to your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

That's difficult to say, the easier things that comes to my mind is using a custom config file.

Say you have a `app/config/custom.php` config file:

```
<?php
return array(
  'form' => array(
     'input-class' => 'form-control',
     'label-class' => 'control-label',
   ),
);
```

You could then do

```
{{ Form::password('password', ['class' => Config::get('custom.form.input-class')]) }}
```

If you do the same for every form, a change in your config file would reflect in any of them. This is the closest to what you want, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the following code:

```
{{ Form::password('password', array('class' =>"form-control" )) }}
```

I am using laravel 4.2 and Bootstrap v3.3.0 and this is working fine for me.